# How can I install without a USB or CD? I have tried UNetbootin and wubi

Tags: software-installation

I need help pretty major! I have tried UNetbootin and Wubi To intsall Ubuntu 14.10, neither worked, I have an HP 2000 and am running Windows 7 Ultimate (My computer came pre-installed with Windows 8... Its a long story) anyway! I need help! Please!!!

Edit: I don't have a DVD Rom or a USB Stick, so i need to install it without those, Wubi from what I understand is supposed to have an option to install like an application in windows, im not sure if this was removed with an update or anything. Also when I use wubi it attempts to download another .ISO for Ubuntu when the one I have is perfectly fine and all the files are intact. Untebootin just does not work for me for some reason.

Edit: Thank everyone for their help!! But i got it installed! Yayyyyy

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? Are you having trouble installing Ubuntu, or does the installation media simply not work? If you're getting some kind of error with Wubi, tell us what the problem you get is.

Comment: Why not install it im vmware under windows ?

Comment: @Terrance8D they don't have USB or CD/DVD ROM - I wonder if this is on a tablet or an all in one

Comment: Try netbooting.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi doesn't work with the Windows 8 bootloader. You'll be able to install Ubuntu via Wubi, but you won't be able to boot into it. There isn't a way to properly install Ubuntu through Wubi on Windows 8, nor is there a plan to add support for the Windows 8 bootloader. At this point, your only option may be to buy a flash drive and use that as your boot device.

Sources: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#What_about_Windows_8.3F http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice